# How to customize footnote call-ups with footmisc, fnpct and footnotebackref loaded?

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, back-referencing, footmisc

I would like to customize my footnotes call-ups (the numbers appearing below the footnote rule) by making them non-superscript numbers, perhaps with a trailing dot.

However, since I am loading some packages to make footnotes more appealing, I can't find an easy way to do it: redefining `\@makefntext` breaks things.

This is the MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[hang]{footmisc} % used only for hanged style
\usepackage{fnpct}% fix multiple footnotes separator
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}% hyperlinks to footnotes
\usepackage{footnotebackref}% hyperlinks to text, loads hyperref

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\kant*[1-3]\footnote{this is a ugly and very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long footnote}\footnote{short footnote}

\end{document}
```

Without `footmisc`, which I only use for hanged style, footnotes look like this:

[image]

With the package loaded, they look like this:

[image]

However, I can't find `\@makefntext` anywhere in `footmisc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`footnotebackref` is the main problem: it redefines `\@makefntext` and in it `\@makefnmark`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[hang]{footmisc} % used only for hanged style
\usepackage{fnpct}% fix multiple footnotes separator
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}% hyperlinks to footnotes

\usepackage{footnotebackref}% hyperlinks to text, loads hyperref

\makeatletter 

   \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
        \renewcommand\@makefnmark{%
            \mbox{{\normalfont%
            \hyperref[\BackrefFootnoteTag]{\@thefnmark}}}.}%
        \BHFN@OldMakefntext{#1}}%
\makeatother        
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\kant*[1-3] \par abc\footnote{this is a ugly and very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long footnote}\footnote{short footnote}

\end{document}
```

[image]